# Unsure what's causing this error in R (pmvt - Package: mvtnorm)?

Tags: r, error-handling, statistics, syntax-error

I have a simple hazard function, the line causing the error is marked.

```
h <- function(t,u) {
    x <- 1 - Sa(t)
    y <- 1 - Sm(u)
    invx <- as.numeric(qt(x,df=d1))
    invy <- as.numeric(qt(x,df=d1))
    [ERROR LINE] copula <-  pmvt(lower=as.numeric(cbind(-9999,-9999)),upper=cbind(invx,invy),df=d1,corr=matrix(cbind(1,d2,d2,1),byrow=T,ncol=2)  )
    density <- dmvt(cbind(invx,invy),sigma=matrix(cbind(1,d2,d2,1),byrow=T,ncol=2),df=d1)
    num <- (sa(t)*sm(u))*density/dt(invx,df=d1)/dt(invy,df=d1)
    den <- 1 - x - y + copula
    hazard <- num/den
    return(hazard)
}
```

This hazard function is then called on by a likelihood function:

```
# log Likelihood function for each individual car i
lli <- function(data) {
  result <- 0;
  # for all claims, evaluate hazard function at that point
  if (nrow(data)> 2) {
    for (k in 1:nrow(data)) {
      if (data[k,3] == 1) {
    result <- result + log(h(data[k,2],data[k,1]));
      }
     }
  }
  # integrate hazard function over areas between claims
  for (k in 1:(nrow(data)-1)) {
    integral <- quad2d(h,data[k,2],data[k+1,2],data[k,1],data[k+1,1]);
    result <- result - integral;
  }
  return(result)
}
```

Now this likelihood function is then called on by a third function to use over my entire data set; **however it is the above function that is causing the error, not the function below**

```
# log Likelihood function over all vehicles
ll <- function(x) {
# Unpack parameters
  d1 <<- x[1];
  d2 <<- x[2];
  total <- 0;
  # Get log Likelihood for each vehicle
  for (i in 1:length(alldata)) {
    total <- total + lli(alldata[[i]]);
    #print(sprintf("Found candidate solution %d value: %f",i,total));
  }
  #print(sprintf("Found candidate solution value: %f",total));
  if (is.nan(total)) { #If it is undefined, make it a large negative number
    total <- -2147483647 ;
  }
  return(-1*total); # Minimise instead of maximise
}
```

Error message is as follows:

```
> ll(cbind(50,0.923))
Error in checkmvArgs(lower = lower, upper = upper, mean = delta, corr = corr,  : 
  ‘diag(corr)’ and ‘lower’ are of different length
```

I kept getting this same error when using pmvnorm, and ended up having to use the pbivnorm package to get around this. I can't find an alternative package for the bivariate t distribution though. I don't understand what the problem is. When I call the function h(t,u) by itself it executes without a problem. But when lli(data) calls h(t,u), it doesn't work. What's even more bizarre is that they are the same length.

```
> length(as.numeric(cbind(-9999,-9999)))
[1] 2
> length(diag(matrix(cbind(1,d2,d2,1),byrow=T,ncol=2)))
[1] 2
```

I apologize for the messy code. I don't use R much. Anyway this has me completely stumped.

Data file is here: https://files.fm/u/yx9pw2b3

---

Additional code I forgot to include, basically some constants and marginal CDF functions:

Marginals.R:

```
p1 <- 0.4994485;
p2 <-  0.2344439;
p3 <- 0.1151654;
p4 <- 0.1509421;

b1 <- 0.7044292
t1 <- 1713.3170267
mu1 <- 7.014415
sig1 <- 1.394735
mu2 <- 6.926146
sig2 <- 1.056647
mu3 <- 6.7995896
sig3 <- 0.7212853
b2 <- 0.6444582
t2 <- 762.9962093
b3 <- 1.494303
t3 <- 410.828780

b1 <- 0.903
t1 <- 864.896
b2 <- 0.9109 
t2 <- 314.2946
# Marginal survival distribution and density
Sa <- function(t) {return(exp(-(t / t1) ** b1))}
Sm <- function(u) {return(exp(-(u / t2) ** b2))} 
sa <- function(t) {return((t / t1) ** b1 * b1 * exp(-(t / t1) ** b1) / t ) }
sm <- function(u) {return((u / t2) ** b2 * b2 * exp(-(u / t2) ** b2) / u ) }
```

Comment: Have you tried examining the calling chain with `traceback()`. If that's not helpful then post a small dataset (using `dput`) for which this operation fails with that error.

Comment: Hi, how should I use dput? I typed dput(alldata,"exampledata") and got a strange file which didn't make much sense.

Comment: It's causing the error by feeding the wrong data into the other function. Comment out every thing from the "Error line" down in the function and then start printing out each of the objects referenced in the error line.

Comment: Leave it to us to figure out what the `dput` output means. We need a starting place to work with code.

Comment: dput() file added to main post in txt form. Full datahas 43,000 or so "cars", I included the first 5

Comment: Just for context, each car has points associated with it: These are measures of (age, mileage) at some time. A 0 indicates a claim was not made at that time, a 1 indicates a claim was made. The final row of each car is when they leave the warranty coverage. Each car can have no or multiple claims (ie some cars have 3, others have 0).

Comment: What are the `Sa` and `Sm` functions in the provided `h` function?

Comment: I replaced with some dummy functions. Can't repro your error. Suggest you provide a complete example that can reproduce the error, but please try to make it minimal by commenting or stripping out code that is unnessary to get the error. For example, is everything else irrelevant except the call to `pmvt` if you could trace the data going into the call producing the error?

Comment: Hi @A.Webb, my code reproduces the error using just the code presented here. The only difference is I load the h() function using source("Copula.R") and the dataset using load("alldata.rData").
I think that perhaps it would be more useful if you had the entire dataset. so I have uploaded the .rDatafile here. https://files.fm/u/yx9pw2b3. ---

Also, I just saw the comment above yours. There is one more file sourced that has some files and marginal functions. I will include that in the original post. That is where Sa(m) etc come from .Sorry!

Comment: Going through my code, the error seems to arise when I integrate using the quad2d function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Summary:**
The problem is the difference length between `lower` and `upper` when calling `pvmt`, which `upper` has a length of 2048, while `lower` has length of 2.

**Reasoning:**
1. `pmvt` checks the coming parameters by calling `checkmvArgs` in `mvtnorm` package.
2. In `checkmvArgs`, `lower`, `upper` and `mean` have been put together by `rec <- cbind(lower, upper, mean)`.  Here the new data `rec` has 2048 row instead of 2.
3. `lower` is then replace by `lower <- rec[, "lower"]`, which `lower` now has length 2048 instead of 2.
4. Given `corr` is still a 2 * 2 matrix, error occurs when checking `length(corr) != length(lower)`

**Solution:**

```
  invx <- as.numeric(qt(x,df=d1))  
  invy <- as.numeric(qt(x,df=d1))
```

`upper` mean to be a length 2 vector, hence `invx` and `invy` needs to be single numbers.

As not sure what's the upper range you want to define, I cannot solve it further. Possible one is :

```
  invx <- as.numeric(qt(x,df=d1))
  invy <- as.numeric(qt(x,df=d1))
  copula <-  pmvt(lower=as.numeric(cbind(-9999,-9999)),upper=range(c(invx,invy)),df=d1,corr=matrix(c(1,d2,d2,1),byrow=T,ncol=2)  )
```

Which is using the range of `invx` and `invy` as the input. Hence the `dmvt` would not be affect.

**Note:**
As value `a` is not provided, the next line below (calling `dmvt`) the error line failed.

**Edit:**
To make the issue more specific:
1. `quad2d` will generate a Gauss-Legendre Quadrature which will be created by default a length of 32 on a given range. And,
2. Your function `h` is then called with the x and y from this Gauss-Legendre Quadrature. Hence, the `t` and `u` defined in `h` is not a single mumber, instead, it is a vector.

Comment: I don't understand why you believe upper has length 2048? Here invx and invy are just numbers, and so when I bind them they get length 2? I tried using the range(c(invx,invy)) and error still occurred. It is very difficult for me to understand this error. 

Also, sorry, that "a" was a typo. It should be a 1. I have corrected that.

Thanks for your attempt at help!

Comment: @Patty, I found this issue as I debug and trace the code from the `ll` function. As you mentioned, the issue is loacted in `quad2d` function in whcih a `Mesh` grid is generated and used as the input calling `h` function.  The problem is that the `Mesh` grid is not a 2x2 matrix.

Comment: I understand now. I made a mistake interpreting your answer. It fixed everything. 谢谢你！You've helped me a really massive amount, thank you so much. Wish I could have given a bigger bounty.